# Scala: Use Java Constructor with Subclasses in Scala

Tags: java, scala, constructor, subclass

I want to use a constructor, that is written in Java, in Scala.

The constructor is declared in that way:

```
public <SUBCLASS extends Node> NodeDock(Parent<? super Node> parent, Class<SUBCLASS> cls, LookupCriteria<SUBCLASS>[] criteria) {
   this(parent, cls, 0, criteria);
}
```

So if i want to use it:

```
val task = new NodeDock(scene.asParent(), classOf[FXTaskStackElement].asInstanceOf[Class[_]], new LookupCriteria[FXTaskStackElement]() {...}
```

Scala is giving me always an error that he cannot find the appropriate constrcutor with these parameters.
So how can i get the SUBCLASS of FXTaskStackElement for the LookupCriteria?

Edit:
In Java i would call this constrcutor like that, which works fine:

```
task = new NodeDock(scene.asParent(), FXTaskStackElement.class, new LookupCriteria<FXTaskStackElement>() {...})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `classOf[FXTaskStackElement].asInstanceOf[Class[_]]` instead of just `classOf[FXTaskStackElement]`? Since your second argument is a `Class[_]`, there is no suitable `SUBCLASS`.

Comment: Oh my god, i have searched for the wrong problem... thank you, that was the point, i had to use .asInstanceOf for another constructor without it whould have not worked. So i thought that i have to use it with this constructor as well, but it works now with: val task = new NodeDock(scene.asParent(), classOf[FXTaskStackElement], new LookupCriteria[FXTaskStackElement]() {...}